# Java - Is there Java equivalent for C# new keyword in method signature? How I can replace final methods in Java?

Tags: c#, java

As you maybe know, as Java language perspective all method in C# are final by default (also vice versa, all methods in Java are virtual as C# language perspective).

In C# we can replace final (non-virtual) methods by `new` keyword ([please see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). There is not anyway to replace final methods in Java?

Edit 1:

I just want to mention that method replacing is not same with method overriding. Please run this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ComapreOverrideWithNew
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cat = new Cat();
            cat.PrintNameByNew();
            Console.WriteLine(cat.GetNameByNew());
            cat.PrintNameByOverride();
            Console.WriteLine(cat.GetNameByOverride());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Animal
    {
        public String GetNameByNew()
        {
            return "Animal";
        }
        public void PrintNameByNew()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetNameByNew());
        }

        public virtual String GetNameByOverride()
        {
            return "Animal";
        }
        public void PrintNameByOverride()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetNameByOverride());
        }
    }
    class Cat : Animal
    {
        new public String GetNameByNew()
        {
            return "Cat";
        }

        public override String GetNameByOverride()
        {
            return "Cat";
        }
    }
}
```

For example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html is just talking about overriding. Also this code have not any compiler warning on compilation.

Comment: I think this is a matter of design intent. In C#, a method being non-virtual could simply be an oversight (as it is the default, like you mentioned). In Java, being non-virtual requires explicit intent, which implies the method's implementation is critical to the proper functioning of the class and its descendents. To allow the `new` keyword to take on this role in Java would violate the open-closed principal.

Comment: Of-course it is. I want to just be sure about it :)

Comment: The intent of final in java is just that - prevent people form 'modifying'. I would suggest to work with the language no against ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace final methods in Java.

Comment: Well it's not a matter of replacing so much as hiding, right? It's a naming issue really.

Comment: If you don't need to expose them, you can just make them private. Otherwise you need to choose a different name or overload a method with different set of parameters (if you want to keep the same name).

Answer (score 1):

[There's no such thing in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html). A final method cannot be overridden.

Comment: There's no such thing as method "replacing".

Comment: Again: there's such thing. If the method is visible, you can only override it if it's not final. If it's not visible, then you're not hiding/replacing/new method anything (since it's not visible).

Answer (score 0):

All the `new` keyword does in C# is suppress a compiler warning.

Comment: I can not see compiler warning, please see my example that I added in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create a "new" final method in java is if the method is marked private.  The following is legal:

```
public class A  
{
   private final void go(){};
}

class B extends A  
{  
    private final void go() {};
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, didn't thought about it, but technically, B's go() does not "replace" A's go() method.

Comment: @m0skit0 correct and technically B doesn't even know about A.go .  Also why I put "new" in quotes

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi the java spec was set up to make it so you cannot do what you want.